# PHP If/Else Argument and PDO Objects

Tags: php, if-statement, pdo

How can I make an argument if/else with the following. I would like to define the variable $condition as the intersection of Table A and Table B, and ultimately, where this condition is true, then execute some code.

Here is the PHP I have (I am trying to match up the table1.field1 and table2.field1 and where true, then I will add a CSS class to the `<tr>`)

```
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4 FROM table1 ORDER BY field1 DESC");
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$match = $dbh->query("SELECT table1.field1 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 WHERE table2.field1 = table1.field1");

$condition = **???????**
```

Also, is there a way to simplify this code? I feel like its too long. Mark Twain has a saying... "I'm sorry this letter is too long, I didn't have time to make it shorter". I wish I could say that this is relevant here, but I've been at this for a while! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I hope you tables and columns actually have sane names

Comment: f is for fun. coding can be fun.

Comment: Well. Fun aside, but it makes it kinda hard to tell how the above can be improved. Also the fact that `t1` suddenly becomes `f1` in your second query makes it even harder.

Comment: thanks for that. I've made the change. t is short for table and f is short for field. I can edit this question to make it more readable.

Comment: This question is quite strange. Can't you simply use `if($match['f1'] == 'whatever'){} ` ?

Comment: Here is what I will include in the `<tr>` tag `if ($condition) echo 'class="match"';
?>>`

Comment: The absolute same applies - `$contition = ($match['f1'] == 'something')`. This will return true or false. You can also check @Halil Özgür's answer which should suite your need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about something like (in your first and then-only query)

```
$result = $dbh->query("
    SELECT
        t1.field1,
        t1.field2,
        t1.field3,
        t1.field4,
        IF(t2.field1 IS NULL, 0, 1) `match`
    FROM
    table1 t1
        LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.field1 = t1.field1
");
```

(you should put backticks (`` ` ``) around `match`, since it's a MySQL keyword)
and in your loop

```
<tr class="<?=$v["match"] ? "match" : ""?>">
```

Comment: Is this killing like 5 birds with one stone by defining the variable withing the SQL statement?

Comment: Haha :) At least 3 birds: as long as I didn't miss your point completely, it should save you from the (possibly costly) other query (if you were using it only for this), and simplify things (matching records using the two queries etc) along the way.

Comment: something not working with the syntax when I try it though... here is the actual query... `SELECT aif_id, fee_source_id, company_name_per_sedar, document_filing_date, (a_aif_remaining.aif_id IS NULL, 0, 1) match
FROM a_aif
LEFT JOIN a_aif_remaining WHERE a_aif_remaining.aif_id = a_aif.aif_id
ORDER BY aif_id DESC;'

Comment: Error Message: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match FROM a_aif LEFT JOIN a_aif_remaining WHERE a_aif_remaining.aif_id = a_aif.' at line 1

Comment: @BenJones ah sorry, forgot `IF` and backticks around `match`, see my edited answer above. Also note that there is a `ON` instead of `WHERE` after `LEFT JOIN`. If you edit your question and include actual field and table names, I can edit my answer accordingly, too.

Comment: yes match is a reserved word. are Case and If the same? and could you please explain the second part of your answer in a bit more depth? I'm not sure what each component stands for.

Comment: I haven't had any success with implementing this and wondering if you would be able to help me out here... please refer to this link for the updated question, thanks

http://stackoverflow.com/q/14135361/1788087

Comment: @BenJones please remove that question and update this question instead. You should use your iteration variable in place of `$v`; based on your other question, it looks like it should be `$row`. Yes, `IF` and `CASE` are reserved words but you do not need to put backticks if you are not using them as custom identifier names (e.g. column/variable names).