# Why is this not changing the class of the table in my row?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I can see the html table generated, but the rows are not highlighting based on the CSS class I have defined called "match"? My goal is to highlight each row that satisfies the match condition, as defined in the SQL query. I think the error has something to do with the variable `match` being defined in the SQL query as opposed to the PHP?

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$result = $dbh->query("
    SELECT a_aif.aif_id,
      a_aif.fee_source_id,
      a_aif.company_name_per_sedar,
      a_aif.document_filing_date,
      IF (a_aif_remaining.aif_id IS NULL, 0, 1) `match`
    FROM  a_aif
      LEFT JOIN a_aif_remaining
        ON a_aif_remaining.aif_id = a_aif.aif_id
    ORDER BY aif_id DESC");

$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ( !empty($result) ) : endif;

?>

<table>
<tr>
    <th><b>Document ID</b></th>
    <th><b>Pubco Name</b></th>
    <th><b>Filing Date</b></th>
    <th><b>PDF</b></th>
</tr>

<?php foreach($result as $index => $row) : ?>
<tr class="<?=$v["match"] ? "match" : ""?>">
    <td><?php echo $row[fee_source_id]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[company_name_per_sedar]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[document_filing_date]; ?></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;
$dbh = NULL;
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you see the output in developer toolbar was the class applied or not?

Comment: what developer toolbar is that? Using Google Chrome, there was no style applied. But I can also instead just see the row that I wanted to be highlighted and it's not highlighted

Comment: `$v["match"]`? Shouldn't that be something like `$row["match"]`?

Comment: @Passerby THANNNNNNNNNKKKKK YOUUUUUUUUUU!

Comment: Exact duplicate of [PHP If/Else Argument and PDO Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115570/php-if-else-argument-and-pdo-objects) - see the comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115570/php-if-else-argument-and-pdo-objects/14115604#comment19572177_14115604

Comment: @BenJones, please do not open exact duplicates of unresolved questions, just edit your original question.